# Want to add back the removed param by the user using Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If the user removes the param from the url manually. I want to add back the value of the param in the url using Angular 6. Let's say,

`https://localhost:4200/root/param1/product`

Here user is removing param1 from the url,

so, now the url will be like this,

`https://localhost:4200/root//product`

and it is redirecting to login page. But I don't want that redirection.

I am using resolve here.

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
const param1 = route.paramMap.get('opportunity');
if (param1 === null) {
    this.cart.createOpportunityId().subscribe((opp) => {
          this.router.navigate(['/root', opp, route.url[3].path]);
    });
 }
}
```

Here I have written a condition to find whether the param is null. 
But when i tried to remove the param1 manually. The page is redirecting. 
I am facing this issue when the param value is null and when it is wrong param value,  url is working fine. 
Please help me out to find if user manually removes the param from the url, how to find it is null and how to add back real value.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the param ?

Comment: As per the client requirement if the user removes the param manually, they want to add back the value.

Comment: have you check out https://angular.io/api/common/Location? location.back() is the function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, like you said if you remove param then page redirects, then the reason must be you have defined such routes in your routing module.
Like:

```
{path: '/root/:anotherParam', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'}
{path: '/root/:opportunity/:anotherParam', Component: ComponentB}
```

When second route fails to match as there is no param opportunity, first route matches, then it redirects you to login route.
Like you said if you provide wrong param value, it works because it matches with the second route(having wrong opportunity). 
For redirecting purpose you should reconsider your routes.
You can also use localstorage or sessionStroage(will be best) to store the user param and then check the param in the routes, if there is no such param, then you can get it from local/sessionStorage.
Hope it helps you.